# Firestore update nested objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a message object in a nested map. As you can see in the screenshot below, I want to go in "us" then "0" then "messages" to add my object.
[image]

I have used the following script :

> firestore.collection("salon").document(idSalon).update(
> "us.0.messages",message
> );

When I use it, it just overwrites everything as you can see.
[image]

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: can you refer to this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, the "us" field is of type array. To be able to update an array, you should use `arrayUnion` and **not** a simple field update. For that I recommend you check the official documentation regarding [update elements in a Firestore array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array).

I have also written an article called:

- [How to update an array of objects in Firestore?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073)

That I think it will help you understand this topic better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I have tried the following script : 
`firestore.collection("salon").document(idSalon).update("us",FieldValue.arrayUnion(message));` 
Obviously, it doesnt udapte the thing, I want. Indeed, I want to update in "us" array, in the number 0, then "messages". Do I need to copy the entire US array, to modify and then write it back to firestore or is it possible to give a path to update in this array ? I can't find my answer.

Comment: To be able to perform that update, you should first find the object that you want to update in the array, remove it and add the new (updated) one. Have you read the [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-update-an-array-of-objects-in-firestore-cdb611a56073) in my answer?

Comment: Yes I rode it. The fact is that I don't want to delete anything to replace it. I have an array of messages, I just want to add a new one, not replace one.

Comment: Ok, I understood. You said you have used `firestore.collection("salon").document(idSalon).update("us",FieldValue.arrayUnion(message));`, but *Obviously, it doesnt udapte the thing*. Why? What's the value of `idSalon`?

Comment: idSalon is the id of the current saloon. On my app, I have different saloon. So in the saloon with the idSalon, I want to add a message. In Firebase, idSalon is the document id like "wPbnw....d7q" in the screenshot I gave.

Comment: So what happens when you use `firestore.collection("salon").document(idSalon).update("us",FieldValue.arrayUnion(message));`?

Comment: It creates my message in the "us" array. Now I want to add it "us/0/messages" my message

Comment: In that case, you should read the document, read the object at position zero, and add a new one. In the end, write the document back. However is more convenient to use those messages as documents, and not as object inside an array.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help

Comment: You're very welcome, EPetit.